# Keras modelling: Do I need one-hot encoding and if so how?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I would like to have your help with setting up a model with Keras. I have a dataset which contains interval data like age or salary. Then it also contains e.g. sex (male/female) or department (sales/HR/finance/service).

I assume that for e.g. "sex" I might go for 0/1 . But for department 1/2/3/4 I assume I better use one-hot encoding?

If so, I'm not clear about how the dataframe should look like. Let's just look at three fields:

```
EmpNo    Sex    Dept
1        0      [0,0,1,0]
2        1      [0,0,0,1]
3        0      [1,0,0,0]
4        0      [0,0,1,0]
```

Or would it need to look like this:

```
EmpNo    Sex    Dept_1    Dept_2    Dept_3    Dept_4
1        0      0         0         1         0
2        1      0         0         0         1
3        0      1         0         0         0
4        0      0         0         1         0
```

As you can see I'm not clear what and how it can be processed in Keras. Of course the second one can be processed but I would find a first setup nicer to control.
Any other comments? Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataframe would look like the second type:

```
EmpNo    Sex    Dept_1    Dept_2    Dept_3    Dept_4
1        0      0         0         1         0
2        1      0         0         0         1
3        0      1         0         0         0
4        0      0         0         1         0
```

You're changing the single column multi-categorical data into multiple column single-categorical data.
refer: https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/

Comment: Thank you Anuj for the link. So I go that path!